# KeepAlived and HAProxy VIP Appears Twice

Tags: haproxy, keepalived

```
Linux Distribution: CentOS 9 Stream
Version of HA Proxy: HAProxy version 2.4.22-f8e3218
Version of KeepAlived: Keepalived v2.2.8 (04/04,2023
```

I'm protecting 2x HAProxy load-balancers using keepalived in a master/backup configuration. I'm seeing the VIP appear on BOTH the master and slave - when I understand the VIP should only appear once - and should transfer back to the master when it comes back online. I can fail the master and everything works - and power the master backup and operation is not impacted. But I'm not satisfied the configuration is correct

The Master when running

```
sudo ip a | grep ens192

2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.17/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
    **inet 192.168.1.20/32** scope global ens192
```

The Backup when running sudo ip a | grep ens192

```
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.19/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
    **inet 192.168.1.20/32** scope global ens192
```

The Master Configuration looks like this:

```
global_defs {
  router_id LB-01
}
vrrp_script haproxy {
  script "killall -0 haproxy"
  interval 2
  weight 2
}
vrrp_instance 50 {
  virtual_router_id 50
  advert_int 1
  priority 150
  state MASTER
  interface ens192
  virtual_ipaddress {
     192.168.1.20
  }
  track_script {
      haproxy
  }
}
```

And the Backup Configuration looks like this:

```
global_defs {
  router_id LB-02
}
vrrp_script haproxy {
  script "killall -0 haproxy"
  interval 2
  weight 2
}
vrrp_instance 50 {
  virtual_router_id 50
  advert_int 1
  priority 50
  state BACKUP
  interface ens192
  virtual_ipaddress {
     192.168.1.20
  }
  track_script {
    haproxy
  }
}
```

I read somewhere that there has to be 50 points between the master & backup priority number. I've confirmed that the router instance ID is identical on both systems...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So turns out software update was required. Also SELinux blocks script check haproxy so whilst can detect the total lost of a LB it doesn’t detect the failure of the haproxy service

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would share my KeepAlive.conf settings specifically for protecting HAproxy. In this configuration, HAProxy & KeepAliveD are installed to 2x HProxy instances to create a degree of fault tolerance at the LB layer

I setup a backup/backup system with weighted priority - rather than master/backup which means an automatic "fallback" to a default LB. I preferred a setup where the LB with the longest more stable uptime was the preferred system.

```
obal_defs {
  router_id LB-01
}
vrrp_script haproxy {
      script "/usr/local/bin/checkhaproxy.sh"
      interval 1
      timeout 5
      rise 3
      fall 3
}
vrrp_instance 50 {
  virtual_router_id 50
  advert_int 1
  state BACKUP
  priority 150
  nopreempt
  interface ens192
  virtual_ipaddress {
     192.168.1.22
  }
  track_script {
      haproxy
  }
```

The critical thing was having a way of checking the state of HAproxy which was acceptable to SELinux. So a .sh script was created and made executable with chmod +x

```
!/bin/sh
# restart keepalive if haproxy died
pid=`/bin/pidof haproxy`
test -z "$pid" && { service keepalived restart &>/dev/null; exit 1; }
exit 0
```

This was stored in /usr/local/bin/

On the backup1 called LB-02 the shame .sh script was created in /usr/local/bin and the conf file looks like this:

```
global_defs {
  router_id LB-02
}
vrrp_script haproxy {
      script "/usr/local/bin/checkhaproxy.sh"
      interval 1
      timeout 5
      rise 3
      fall 3
}
vrrp_instance 50 {
  virtual_router_id 50
  advert_int 1
  state BACKUP
  priority 50
  nopreempt
  interface ens192
  virtual_ipaddress {
     192.168.1.22
  }
  track_script {
    haproxy
  }
}
```

The two files are almost identical except for:

The router ID hostname (validate LB-01 can ping LB-02 and vice versa)
The priority value is lower on LB-02 to ensure if they both come up at the same time one wins in the election

Gotchas - obliviously the VIP is relative to your network - and watch out for how different linux distros enumerate nics - aka ens192 and eth0 and so on....

Comment: So it's generaly advisable to have identical setups (hardware, OS and software) on systems that are managed as a HA with keepalived. They certainly shouldn't be different linux distros.

Comment: Agreed. My two LB are identical. What I do find is our different linux distros enumerate nic IDs differently from each and also dependent on the platform. One linux distro running in say vSphere will report ens192 where as the same distro in Hyper-V will report etho depending on the generation of VM. As the haproxy.conf has a hardcode reference to nic address is could be an easy to over look